# mergeMap with pipe in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, http

I'm a newbie; please bear with me.

I need to get a list of Id's ids => this.getIds() and get their names => getNames(id) for each id in the list of ids using mergeMap(). Can someone please check what I'm doing wrong below (it fails to compile)?

```
interface Id{
            "Id": string;
            "Name": string;
}
export interface Ids extends Array<Id>{}
```

in myservice.ts

```
 getIds():Ids {
  return this.http
  .post(url1, '')
  .pipe(map(({ Ids}: Ids) => Ids.map(item => ({Id: item.Id }))));
 }
getNames():Observable<any[]> {
 return this.http
    .post(url2, '')
    .pipe(map(({ Names }: any) => Names.map(item => ({Sid: item.Id, Name: item.Name }))));
}
```

in mycomponent.ts,

```
getIds(): void {
 this.myservice
  .getIds.pipe(
  mergeMap(id => this.getNames(id)),
  mergeMap(names => names),
  toArray()
  )
}
getNames(): void {
 this.myservice
 .getNames(ids)
 .subscribe(val => this.data = val);
}

ERROR in src/app/myservice.ts(24,5): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'Ids'.
Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Observable<any>'.
src/app/myservice.ts(26,17): error TS2459: Type 'Ids' has no property 'Ids' and no string index signature.
src/app/mycomponent.ts(128,20): error TS2339: Property 'pipe' does not exist on type '() => Ids'.
src/app/mycomponent.ts(129,35): error TS2345: Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Ids'.
Property 'includes' is missing in type '{}'. src/app/mycomponent.ts(130,19): error TS2345: Argument of type '(vulns: {}) => {}' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: {}, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Iterable<{}>'.
Property '[Symbol.iterator]' is missing in type '{}'.
```

Comment: I suspect your `getIds():Ids` has a wrong signature. Should it be `getIds():Observable<Ids>`?

Comment: Tried that; didnt make a diff.

Comment: In your error you have line numbers `(24,5)` which lines are these? Your function call to `getIds()` inside your components should be called with `this.myservice
  .getIds().pipe` otherwise you're trying to call `.pipe` on the function and not on the function results. Try to read the lines mentioned in the error.

Comment: Fixed the getIds(). 
The error on (24,5) is the line from myservice.ts - .pipe(map(({ Ids}: Ids) ...

Comment: Change `getIds():Ids` to `getIds():Observable<Ids>` and end the return statement with `({Id: item.Id })))) as Observable<Ids>`.

Comment: sorry; need help with the syntax here. Do you mean, replace the following,
.pipe(map(({ Ids}: Ids) => Ids.map(item => ({Id: item.Id }))));
with,
.pipe(map(({ Ids}: Ids) => Ids.map(item => ({Observable<Ids>: item.Id }))));

Comment: Just append `as Observable<Ids>` to the end of the function so that it looks like `.pipe(map(({ Ids}: Ids) => Ids.map(item => ({Id: item.Id })))) as Observable<Ids>;`

Comment: What is wrong with the line `src/app/myservice.ts(26,17): error TS2459: Type 'Ids' has no property 'Ids' and no string index signature`. This is the line `.pipe(map(({ Ids}: Ids) => Ids.map(item => ({Id: item.Id }))));`

Comment: I'm having trouble with the syntax here. Can you please look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53235705/enforce-order-using-pipe-with-mergemap-in-angular)?